# Gradle: Override exclude config made in a plugin

Tags: gradle, liferay

I'm developing a Liferay 7.2 theme (WAR-style) using Liferays "Gradle Theme Builder". I configured it to generate CSS source maps, too. This works fine, except that the original SCSS files are not deployed with the theme WAR file -- the source maps, on the other hand, are deployed. In the end, the DevTools in the browser ask the server for about 200 non-existent SCSS source files, which I cannot assign by hand to a local file (it looks like Firefox and Chrome removed that feature a while ago; and no matter how much I play with local files and workspaces in the DevTools, I cannot get the browser to recognize the local files as "these are the sources I'm looking for!").

I tried to configure the gradle war task to include those scss files in the resulting WAR, but:
The Theme Builder is a gradle plugin which configures the `war` task programmatically and sets an exclude to `**/*.scss` (see the [sources here](https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/modules/sdk/gradle-plugins-theme-builder/src/main/java/com/liferay/gradle/plugins/theme/builder/ThemeBuilderPlugin.java#L292)). Changing that plugin is out of question, so how can I override that exclude in my `build.gradle`?

Alternatively, I tried to run a second war task after the first, with the intention of adding those scss files to the existing WAR file (having the added benefit of a different task to run if I want a "theme development build"):

```
task fragmentWAR(type: War) {
    group 'build'
    description 'Prepares a war with scss files'
    dependsOn war 

    from('build/buildTheme') {
        include '**/*.scss'
        exclude '**/.sass-cache'
    }
}

task fragmentDeploy {
    group 'build'
    description 'Goes to war with scss files'
    dependsOn += fragmentWAR
    dependsOn += deploy
}

deploy.mustRunAfter(fragmentWAR)
```

But that messes up the WAR file: some files are now created twice in the WAR, others are missing completely.

In the end, I need a way to deploy the scss files along with the transpiled css and the css source maps into my testing server. Has anybody got any idea how to circumvent that exclude configured by the theme builder plugin -- or any other idea that might help me here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the generator-liferay-theme NPM module instead of the Gradle Theme Builder plugin? Use v9.x of generator-liferay-theme for Liferay 7.2.

See
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-js-themes-toolkit and
https://github.com/liferay/liferay-js-themes-toolkit/tree/master/packages/generator-liferay-theme for more details.

When I generate my theme using this module, I see that both .scss and .css.map are files included in my theme .war file.

Hope it helps.

Comment: I burned everything nodejs- and npm-related on my machine after trying to get that stuff to run.

Comment: If you're willing to give it a shot again, I'd recommend installing https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm. NVM makes it easy to manage and switch between multiple versions of NodeJS on your machine. Which is very nice when you run into some NPM package that required a certain Node version.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not willing to try that again. I already lost 3 days on that topic.

Comment: Also, the main problem I got with the generator-liferay-theme is that it requires waaaaay too many small files in dependency packages, running unbearably slow on this workplace machine where I cannot switch off the on-access virus scanner and then the yeoman post-install script failing with not heeding the corporate proxy settings. Nope. Not trying that again.